# Completeness and being totally bounded

Tags: general-topology, uniform-spaces

Are completeness and being totally bounded somehow related with each other for uniform spaces?

Comment: Well, there is kind of a relation, a space is compact if and only if it is both, complete and totally bounded.

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "related somehow": $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology is a uniform space that is complete but _not_ totally bounded.